# can't access Image after uploade in asp core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't access photos to view after uploade.
This is the uploade code 
`

```
public async Task<string> Upload_Image(FormFile file,string name)
        {
            var newFileName = string.Empty;
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = string.Empty;
                string PathDB = string.Empty;

                //Getting FileName
                fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                //Assigning Unique Filename (Guid)
                var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

                //Getting file Extension
                var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                // concating  FileName + FileExtension
                newFileName = myUniqueFileName + FileExtension;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_env.WebRootPath))
                {
                    _env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), name);
                }
                // Combines two strings into a path.
                fileName = _env.WebRootPath + '\\' + newFileName;

                // if you want to store path of folder in database
                PathDB = name+"/" + newFileName;
                newFileName = PathDB;
                using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                    fs.Flush();
                }
            }

            return newFileName;

        }`
```

I am using `ID` as argument for parameter 'name'.
When I am trying to access the photo using "/ID/whatEverhere.jpg"
return NOTFOUND  ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your file in :

```
 fileName = _env.WebRootPath + '\\' + newFileName;`  
 ...
 using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
```

And you return :

```
PathDB = name+"/" + newFileName;
newFileName = PathDB;
...
return newFileName;
```

So, that isn't the same path, there isn't your ID in the path you store the file !
I sujest you should cleanup your code.